Почему браузер переходит по ссылкам, а любые другие программы - нет?
На компьютере корпоративная сеть. Из-за неё почти все интернет-запросы от программ, таких как Git, Eclipse IDE, Visual Studio Code и т.д., падают с разными ошибками. Но если ссылку, по которой они не достучались, ввести в браузере и перейти по ней - всё без проблем откроется. Например, VS Code не может проверить обновление - для этого у неё не скачивается небольшой файлик. Если вести ссылку на этот файл в браузере - тот сразу скачается.
Вопрос - почему браузер может, а остальные нет? Что сделать, чтобы они так же, как и браузер, имели беспрепятственный доступ в интернет?

Примеры ошибок:

VS Code при проверке обновлений: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
Eclipse IDE при открытии его маркета (решал добавлением скачанного сертификата по https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ - не помогло): Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


Возможно в браузере указан корпоративный прокси-сервер

@Kromster, добавил. Хотел ещё привести пример с Git'ом, а он, внезапно, стал работать) Не задав этот вопрос, так и сидел бы без него)

@ГерманБорисов, разве что написано "Этим браузером управляет ваша организация.", а прокси не в браузере же указывается, а в настройках винды (там прокси не используется - проверено)

У firefox есть 3 варианта настройки прокси: 1) указать вручную 2) из настроек винды 3) из файла на корпоративном сервере. У нас на работе использовался третий.
